# Database/schema limit on Azure Database for MySQL?

Tags: azure, azure-database-mysql

Is there a limit on the number of databases/schemas I can create on the Azure Database for MySQL platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In official doc about [Azure MySql Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-limits), it doesn't mention the limitation about max number of databases. And the Azure MySql uses MySql database engine, the doc also mention the general limitation apply as well.

Then in MySQL official doc, it did have a description about [Limits on Number of Databases and Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/database-count-limit.html). From this doc you could find the limitation is the file system. For now what I know the maximum number of directories it allows (NTFS ~ 4 billion, ext3 ~32000, ext4 ~unlimited, etc.)

And the last factor limits the number is how much storage you choose for your server.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.